# How to set Visibility of Image according to Carousel View Position in Xamarin Forms?

Tags: xamarin.forms, carousel, visibility

I am using CarouselView in xamarin Forms. I want to display Image at only Current position of CarouselView Item. If I am scrolling left or right in carousel View then Visibility of Image should be changed. How can I achieve this is Xamarin Forms?

My Calendar Item Code is :

```
 <DataTemplate>
                            <ViewCell>
                                <StackLayout HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" Margin="5">
                                    <Label Text="{Binding ShortNameText}" TextColor="{Binding Color}" FontSize="10" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" ></Label>
                                    <Grid HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center">
                                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                            <RowDefinition Height="30*"/>
                                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="30*"/>
                                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                        <Image HorizontalOptions="Center" BindingContext="{x:Reference Name=CarouselMenuItems}" Source="ic_orange_circle.png" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" HeightRequest="30" IsVisible="{Binding Path=., Converter=imageVisibility}" WidthRequest="30">

                                        </Image>
                                        <Label HorizontalOptions="Center" Text="{Binding DateNumber}" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" TextColor="{Binding Color}" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" FontSize="16"/>

                                    </Grid>

                                </StackLayout>
                            </ViewCell>
                        </DataTemplate>
```

My CarouselView code is :

```
<controls:CarouselViewControl x:Name="CarouselMenuItems" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" InputTransparent="False" ItemsSource="{Binding CarousolMenuItemsList}" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" >
                <controls:CarouselViewControl.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ContentView x:Name="ListviewContent">

                            <ListView x:Name="LstMenu" BackgroundColor="#F5F5F5" ItemSelected="LstMenuItemSelected"  ItemTapped="LstMenuItemTapped" 
                                      SeparatorVisibility="None" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                                      HasUnevenRows="True" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource MenuItemTemplateSelector}" 
                                      ItemsSource="{Binding Path=.}" 
                                      CachingStrategy="RecycleElement" Margin="5,5,5,5">

                            </ListView>
                        </ContentView>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </controls:CarouselViewControl.ItemTemplate>
            </controls:CarouselViewControl>
```

And requirement is If i am swipe from below menu cards listview then Orange color Circle Image is visible on that Item's data. If  I am clicking on particular date then menu cards of that date should be display from that carousel View. I am attaching sample Image of UI.

[image: UI Image]

Comment: Why is listview inside a CarouselViewControl?

Comment: Because it's requirement. Items like soup, classic comforts are list, so it might be increased or decreased at any moment.

Comment: <ContentView x:Name="ListviewContent">
<Image Source="{Binding *}/>
</ContentView>

Where * is the Image name from the CarousolMenuItemsList.

Try this!

Comment: Where should I put this code?

Comment: <controls:CarouselViewControl ItemsSource="{Binding CarousolMenuItemsList}"  >
                <controls:CarouselViewControl.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ContentView x:Name="ListviewContent">                           <Image Source="{Binding *}/> 
                            </ListView>
                        </ContentView>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </controls:CarouselViewControl.ItemTemplate>
            </controls:CarouselViewControl>
Where * is the Image name from the CarousolMenuItemsList.